# Convert a curl request API into axios request

Tags: api, curl, axios

I am using an API and I want use axios to fetch this API inside a Vue App

This is the request

`curl --request GET \ --url 'https://api.apimo.pro/agencies' \ --user 'provider:token'`

provider is something like "1234" and token is 'azertyuiop12344...'

I tried something but its not working

```
  mounted() {
axios
  .get({
    baseURL: "https://api.apimo.pro/agencies",
    params: {
      provider: "1234",
      token: "azertyuiop12344..."
    }
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer but my error was most a NuxtJS error than Javascript

For the ones who are looking for simple Javascript Axios request you should do something like

```js
var axios = require("axios");

axios
  .get("https://api.apimo.pro/agencies", {
    auth: {
      username: "username",
      password: "password"
    }
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error on Authentication");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

> --user parameter in curl used for server authentication. So if you don't define authentication type via other parameters like --digest or --negotiate, it means USER parameter for http basic authentication, it also could be combined with :PASSWORD chunk to set a password as well

it seems that your case is basic authentication so do this:

```
const res = await axios.get('https://api.apimo.pro/agencies', {
  auth: {
    username: '1234',
    password: 'azertyuiop12344...'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the error I got is the following :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.apimo.pro/agencies' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: My code is similar to the code you posted the only difference is the use of await. CORS policy error is something you need to solve with the api server, that must allow the request origin